# Linq add new variable in query

Tags: c#, linq

If i am using grouping by name:

```
List<Recipe> Recipes = Show.GroupBy(t => t.Name)
        .Select(g => new Recipe() { Name = g.Key, components = g.Select(t => new Component {Amount= t.Amount, Ingredient= t.Ingredient })
        .ToList() })
        .ToList();
```

It's write in `Name` value `g.Key` but if i want to add new variable in linq `DishID` how to write there `DishID` from `DisplayRecipe`?

```
List<Recipe> Recipes = Show.GroupBy(t => t.Name)
        .Select(g => new Recipe() { Name = g.Key,DishID= ???, components = g.Select(t => new Component {Amount= t.Amount, Ingredient= t.Ingredient })
        .ToList() })
        .ToList();
```

Model:

```
public class DisplayRecipe
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ingredient { get; set; }
    public string Amount {get;set;}
    public int DishID { get; set; }
}

public class Recipe
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DishID { get; set; }

    public List<Component> components {get;set;}
}

public class Component
{
    public string Ingredient { get; set; }

    public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What if two `Recipe` objects have the same `Name` but different `DishID`? Which `DishID` do you want to use? Or do you want to group also by `DishID`?

Comment: What is the "Show" type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group by `Name` only, then each group might contain items that have different `DishID` values.

If you want to group by both `Name` and `DishID`, then you can do it like this:

```
List<Recipe> Recipes =
    Show.GroupBy(t => new {t.Name, t.DishID})
    .Select(g => new Recipe()
    {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        DishID = g.Key.DishID,
        components = g.Select(t => new Component
        {
            Amount= t.Amount,
            Ingredient= t.Ingredient
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment (at least with example) - if you have:

```
Name     DishId    Components
name1    1         null
name1    2         null
name2    3         null
```

doing a groupby on `Name`, for `name2`, it's obvious you want `DishId` of 3 - but what about for `name` of `name1`?

You have to either specify which DishId to use - `first`, `firstordefault`, etc.  ***Or*** rethink your group by.  You may have intended to group by both fields, if `name` and `dishid` should always be grouped together.